# How to get the release value from an RPM -qi command

Tags: bash

I'm on RedHat, I need to get the value in the Release field.
Take "wget" for an example.

Here's the output I'm expected to get

```
WGET:    1.4.el6
```

Here's the output from rpm -qi wget

```
[luke@machine ~]# rpm -qi wget
Name        : wget                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.12                              Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
Release     : 1.4.el6                       Build Date: Mon May 10 14:56:18 2010
Install Date: Wed Oct  3 16:48:58 2012         Build Host: x86-012.build.bos.redhat.com
Group       : Applications/Internet         Source RPM: wget-1.12-1.4.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 1877597                          License: GPLv3+ and GFDL
Signature   : RSA/8, Mon Aug 16 21:21:35 2010, Key ID 199e2f91fd431d51
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla>
URL         : http://wget.sunsite.dk/
Summary     : A utility for retrieving files using the HTTP or FTP protocols
```

How can I write a script to extract the "1.4.el6" from the Release field.

I currently have

```
#!/bin/bash
RELwg= rpm -qi wget
# Do string manipulation of $RELwg here
wg="WGET:   "
echo $wg$RELwg
```

But here's the output I get;

```
Release     : 1.4.el6                       Build Date: Mon May 10 14:56:18 2010
WGET:
```

I know I have to do some string extraction, to get the number.

- Get the index of the 1, seems to always be constant at 15
- Get the index of the B in Build Date
- Get the sub string inbetween 15 and whatever B is

Removing the space between "RELwg= rpm -qi wget" in my current script, I just get an error saying that

> ./GetRPMVersions.sh: line 12: -qi: command not found

Mainly my current predicament is to addign the ouput of rpm -qi wget | grep Release to a variable.

Any input on the string manipulation is welcome.

Comment: I solved the issue with a $(rpm -qi ...)

Any input on the String manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
RELwg=$(rpm -qi wget | awk -- '/^Release/ { print $3 }')
```

Comment: $(rpm -qi wget | awk -- '/^Release/ { print $3 }')

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
RELwg=$(rpm -q --queryformat='%{RELEASE}' wget)
```

Comment: Can you comment your code? What does it adds to the already accepted answer?

Comment: I am very sorry for not being aware of it.

Comment: No need to be sorry. [Michael's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12786817/296974) takes and tweaks the "common" output, while this one queries exactly what was wanted without having the need to tweak it again. So IMHO it is superior to it. The other one is correct as well, though.